# Salesforce Formula help

Tags: formula-field

I am having problems trying to get a formula to work.

Basically I want `Deposit__c` to display the following

- If `Opportunity_Amount__c *.1` is less than `10k` then display the product of `Opportunity_Amount__C *.1`
- If `Opportunity_Amount__c *.1` is more than `10k` then display `10k` only

I would also like `Deposit__c` to be able to be overridden by the user too.

Comment: IF( Amount * 0.1 <10000, Amount  *0.1, 10000)  it's saying I can't use the Amount in the formula - itsa a standard field.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any updates, and always include **verbatim** text when you have an error message.

Comment: Sorry - The formula I used has worked I was just inserting it on an already created currency field.  When I created a new Formula field it worked.  Thanks for looking at this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula to do the calculation is:

```
MIN(Opportunity_Amount__c * 0.1, 10000)
```

MIN takes the lesser of two numeric values and returns that as the result. It is shorthand for `IF(A < B, A, B)`.

However, in order to allow it to be overridden, you'll need to set up Deposit__c as a regular field, then set up a workflow rule that sets the value when it's not already set (e.g. trigger when Deposit__c equals nothing), or possibly use a checkbox to allow overriding (e.g. when Deposit_Override__c equals false).